# Substitute second occurrence of a pattern in a line using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I need to replace second occurrence of a pattern (that matches the last field) with another and also keep a count of all such changes done in a file.

Example: try.txt

```
Hi

Change apple orange guava mango banana orange

It's hot outside

Change tom greg fred harry steve fred

George is a cool guy

Change mary lucy becky karly jill karly

thank you
```

In all the lines that has pattern "Change", I want to replace the last word, for example "orange" in second line, with say, pear. Note that first orange should not be changed. I also want to put a suffix that shows number of changes happened in the file.

I tried following, but it was changing both the occurences (1st orange and 2nd orange, 1st fred and 2nd fred, 1st karly and 2nd karly), whereas I wanted to change only the second occurence.

```
awk 'BEGIN {cntr=0} {if (/Change/) {gsub($NF,"pear"); OFS=""; print $0,cntr; cntr++} else {print}}' try.txt
```

The output is:

```
Hi

Change apple pear guava mango banana pear0

It's hot outside

Change tom greg pear harry steve pear1

George is a cool guy

Change mary lucy becky pear jill pear2

thank you
```

Desired output is:

```
Hi

Change apple orange guava mango banana pear0

It's hot outside

Change tom greg fred harry steve pear1

George is a cool guy

Change mary lucy becky karly jill pear2

thank you
```

When gsub is replaced with sub, it's changing only first occurrence. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner works for your input:

```
 awk '/Change/{$NF="peal"(i++)}7' file
```

This line will overwrite the `OFS`, however, if you want to keep `OFS` (continuous spaces for example) untouched, you can do:

```
 awk '/Change/{sub(/\S+$/,"peal"(i++))}7' file
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks a  bunch. The first solution worked. But the second one is not changing input. It's printing the file as is.

Comment: @user6129328 Both lines are tested here with gnu awk.

Comment: I also need a small extension to this: What if I have another pattern like "Change2", where all the lines containing this pattern needs to be replaced with, let's say, peal2, and also has its own counter.

Comment: @user6129328 sorry I cannot understand the requirement in your comment. When you asked a question, pls put **all** requirements in the question, not after getting an answer, comment "now I want this, that, and this..."

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a work-around:

awk 'BEGIN {cntr=0} {if (/Change/) {$NF=$NF_cntr; sub($NF,"pear"); OFS=""; print $0,cntr; OFS=" "; cntr++} else {print}}' try.txt

The output was as I desired.

But I still would like to hear from community for better ways of achieving it.

Thanks